# handling out of bounds exceptions in arrays

Tags: java

i am getting an error in my program what does this mean?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at MultiCharacterDisplay.main(MultiCharacterDisplay.java:74)
Java Result: 1
```

this is the code of which i have gotten the error from

```
public void setText(String text) {
    if (text.length() > segmentDisplayCount) {
        text = text.substring(0, segmentDisplayCount);
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (char c: text.toCharArray()) {
        segmentDisplays.get(i++).setCharacter(c);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = args[1];
    MultiCharacterDisplay display = new MultiCharacterDisplay(text.length(), Color.GREEN);
    display.setText(text);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(display);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

After  i run it i get an out of bounds exception, and as of this point i am not sure, why, could someone explain to me please?

Comment: Why are you skipping `args[0]`? Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));`

Comment: hi, its not even printing anything out

Comment: Try running your program with command line arguments. You apparently aren't.

Comment: i dont understand sorry

Comment: `java -jar MyProgram.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4`

Comment: still getting nothing

Comment: Change `String text = args[1];` to `String text = "red";`. Are you using an IDE, or the command line? There isn't enough here to help you.

Comment: i am using an netbeans, i tried it and it finally work, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not passing in at least two arguments in the command line when running the program.  The 1 in args[1] means you are sending two arguments, they occupy spaces 0 and 1.

As @Elliot Frisch pointed out, why are you skipping space 0?  If you want to run it the way you have it now, you need to enter in the command line `Java MultiCharacterDisplay Test 1` where test 1 can be whatever you want, as long as you have two words so they occupy spaces 0 and 1 in your array.

Comment: If you are using an IDE like Netbeans you wouldn't need to set String text = args[1], you would put whatever string you want in there.  ex:  String text = "Test 1";